# How to Sum a column in AWK?

Tags: unix, awk

My file is delimited by a comma which gives 64 columns. I extracted the field as shown below:

```
awk '{split($0,a,",");  print a[57]}'
```

How can I compute the sum of the values in columns 57 with my command?

Comment: Just add `-F ,` to use a different column delimiter.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could sum the column 57 of your file, and print it using

```
awk '{split($0,a,","); sum += a[57]} END {print sum}'
```

Answer (score 149):

The split seems unnecessary here, especially considering you're using awk, which is made for field based processing.  If your file is truly comma-separated, the following code seems much simpler, IMO:

```
awk -F',' '{sum+=$57;} END{print sum;}' file.txt
```

For example, given the following input:

```
    ~$ cat testawk.txt
    a,a,aa,1
    a,a,aa,2
    d,d,dd,7
    d,d,dd,9
    d,dd,d,0
    d,d,dd,23
    d,d,dd,152
    d,d,dd,7
    d,d,dd,5
    f2,f2,f2,5.5
```

We can get the sum like:

```
~$ awk -F',' '{sum+=$4;}END{print sum;}' testawk.txt
   216.5
```

The `-F','` tells awk that the field separator for the input is a comma.

The `{sum+=$4;}` adds the value of the 4th column to a running total.

The `END{print sum;}` tells awk to print the contents of sum after all lines are read.

Comment: why do you need a semicolon after sum?

Comment: @Blaisem - I work with Java a lot and am in the habit of ending statements with them. `awk` uses them as the delimitter between commands,  and this specific code would work with or without the semi's as there are no sequential actions. I've editted the answer to be more consistent in it's usage of semi's since it seems to sporadically get upvotes and views.

Comment: @Blaisem if you do one-liner commands you use semicolon a lot. If you split the awk command in lines they are not needed.